# paste the image I copied into the todo app

Tags: reactjs

I am making a to-do app. How can I add a picture I copied with ctrl+v?

https://mind-board.vercel.app/

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what went unexpected. Share a minimal, reproducible example of the problem you are facing, and you will be much more likely to get an answer to your question.

Comment: I am trying to do a project similar to this. https://ultra.tf

Answer (score 0):

You can read arbitrary clipboard data using this method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read

You could add an event listener that listens to the `paste` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event

and read and do whatever you want with the image from there.